In-app notifications without push notification permissions in a web app
I’m building a PHP application with a web JavaScript front-end and need to send notifications to users within the web app. However, not all users will accept push notifications, so I want to implement in-app notifications that don’t rely on push notification permissions.
I’ve been using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) but encountered a limitation: it seems impossible to receive an FCM token without users opting in to push notifications. This prevents me from using FCM to send in-app notifications as a fallback when push notifications are declined. I also looked into Firebase In-App Messaging, but it doesn’t appear to support JavaScript web apps.
My question is: How can I implement in-app notifications in a JavaScript web application without requiring push notification permissions? Is there a way to use Firebase or FCM to achieve this, or is there another approach I can take to solve this problem?
I’m trying to avoid building a custom solution with WebSockets or Server-Sent Events (SSE) if possible.
Any guidance on how to implement in-app notifications under these constraints would be greatly appreciated.
